Get full Endpoint of a NamedCredential-based HttpRequest without making a SOQL
So you have an ordinary code that makes a callout using Named Credentials:
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('callout:NamedCredentialName/someAdditionalPathHere');
...
HttpResponse ericssonResponse = new Http().send(request);

I'm wondering if I can get an
https://myNamedCredentialRealEndpoint.com/someAdditionalPathHere
instead of
callout:NamedCredentialName/someAdditionalPathHere
that I get with request.getEndpoint() method.
I know that I can SOQL real (https://myNamedCredentialRealEndpoint.com/someAdditionalPathHere) Endpoint. But I really would like to avoid SOQL.
I really hope I'm missing something.
Edit1:
I was using "new" Named Credentials.

I know about SOQL. I want to avoid SOQL. My question is is there any way to avoid SOQL.

@identigral, don't edit my question. You malformed my question. Don't do that.

No.
Using SOQL is the correct way to get the information you're looking for. Other alternatives are either more burdensome or simply not available. I checked a number of alternatives to confirm that SOQL is most likely the only reasonable option. I checked the REST API, because we could trade a SOQL for a callout. Unfortunately, NamedCredential doesn't have an External ID, so you can't get it without a SOQL query. I tried using SOSL, which would be less efficient, but it's not supported anyways. You could use the Metadata API, but that's crazy complicated in Apex, and would definitely take longer than you'd like. About the only thing you could do is to make the call less frequent by using Platform Cache to store the endpoint until it expires. I'm not sure I could justify using Platform Cache to randomly save a SOQL query.

ok, I tried SOQL System.debug([
SELECT Endpoint
FROM NamedCredential
]); and the Endpoint is empty. Callouts work. Is there any additional magic needed?

@AndriiMuzychuk Did a query. Looks like some kinds of named credentials don't have an Endpoint for whatever reason. It definitely works if you use the right endpoint.

I have 3 endpoints, they work when I use them in the Apex, but I don't see values if I SOQL those - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tfMm9P1ZIJAWJA_sZfaFUpokRDtzNF1U/view?usp=sharing . Maybe only Legacy Named Credential work?

Even SOQL is not an option for "new" Named Credentials. As per documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_namedcredential.htm

